# Is there a formula similar to $f(x+a) = e^{a\frac{d}{dx}}f(x)$ to express $f(\alpha\cdot x)$?

Tags: analysis, operator-theory, taylor-expansion

Using the Taylor expansion

$$f(x+a) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^k}{k!}\frac{d^k }{dx^k}f(x)$$

one can formally express the sum as the linear operator $e^{a\frac{d}{dx}}$ to obtain

$$f(x+a) = e^{a\frac{d}{dx}}f(x).$$

But, does a linear operator $\hat A$ exist such that

$$ f(\alpha\cdot x) = \hat A(\alpha) f(x)$$

for some $\alpha\in\mathbb C$?

Comment: $f(a\cdot x)=f(e^{\ln a+\ln x})$ but this is for $a>0$ and $x>0$

Comment: @Norbert thanks, good point! $\alpha\neq 0$ and $x\neq 0$ should be sufficient when complex numbers are ok (the branch cut of $\ln$ shouldn't matter due to the re-exponentiation). So the answer might involve $\frac{d}{d\ln x}$

Comment: @Norbert thanks, I extended this to [an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/116639/163). I wonder about it's general validity though

Comment: Tobias Kienzler, not at all :)

Comment: Please @MrNobody, don't repost your low quality answer, which was already deleted twice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The exponential representation of the Taylor series that you mention is related to the fact that the operator $\mathrm d/\mathrm dx$ is the generator of translations. That is, a translation can be viewed as the exponentiation of an infinitesimal translation, and the corresponding transformation of a function can likewise be viewed as the exponentiation of the transformation corresponding to an infinitesimal translation. To first order, the translation $x\to x+\epsilon$ has the effect $f(x)\to f(x+\epsilon)=f(x)+\epsilon\mathrm d/\mathrm dx f(x)$ and thus corresponds to multiplication with the operator $1+\epsilon\mathrm d/\mathrm dx$; applying this operation $a/\epsilon$ times leads to $ x\to x+a$ and $f\to(1+\epsilon\mathrm d/\mathrm dx)^{a/\epsilon}f$, which goes to $\exp(a\mathrm d/\mathrm dx)f$ for $\epsilon\to0$.

Applying the same approach, we can write $\alpha=\exp(\log\alpha)$ and consider the scaling $x\to\alpha x$ as $\log\alpha/\epsilon$ applications of the infinitesimal scaling $x\to(1+\epsilon)x$. The corresponding infinitesimal transformation of $f$ is $f(x+\epsilon x)=f(x)+\epsilon x\mathrm d/\mathrm dxf(x)=(1+\epsilon x\mathrm d/\mathrm dx)f$, and applying this $\log\alpha/\epsilon$ times and taking $\epsilon\to0$ yields $f\to\exp(\log\alpha x\mathrm d/\mathrm dx)f$. For instance, you can check this for $f(x)=x^n$; in this case $x\mathrm d/\mathrm dx f=nf$, so this yields $f\to\exp(n\log\alpha)f=\alpha^n f$ as expected.

Comment: interesting, so the $x^n$ form the Eigenbase of scaling

Comment: @joriki This is so enlightening!

Comment: @Peter: I'm glad to hear that :-)

Comment: @joriki What is this theory called, or what is it part of?

Comment: @Peter: I learned about this in physics, where it's part of the treatment of continuous symmetry operations like translations and rotations; in mathematics I think it's part of the theory of Lie groups and Lie algebras, and specifically the [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map).

Comment: Here we start with a power series and get an operator.  Is this reversible?  For instance, if I use $\sin$ instead of $\exp$, what is $\sin\!\left(a\frac{d}{dx}\right)f(x)$?

Comment: @Antonio You can ask here in math.SE and you'll surely get an answer.

Comment: @PeterT.off indeed I shall tomorrow.

Comment: @AntonioVargas interesting question, don't forget to post a link here after you posted the question - I think the answer is $\frac1{2i}(f(x+ia) - f(x-ia))$, while using $\cosh$ you'd get the average of $f(x\pm a)$. Now that you mention these, there should be a nice expression for the symmetrization of a function as well, something like $\exp\left(i\frac\pi2\frac d{d\ln z}\right)\cosh\left(i\frac\pi2\frac d{d\ln z}\right)$ (or $\sinh$ for the antisymmetrization)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I have posted the question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/126984/5531).

Answer (score 14):

Based on [Norbert's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116633/is-there-a-formula-similar-to-fxa-ea-fracddxfx-to-express-f-al#comment271095_116633) the answer should be

$$ f(\alpha\cdot x) = \alpha^{x\frac{d}{d x}}f(x)$$

To see this, just define $g(y):=f(e^y)$ such that $f(x) = g(\ln x)$, then one obtains

$$ f(\alpha x) = g(\ln\alpha+\ln x) = e^{\ln\alpha\frac{d}{d\ln x}}g(\ln x)$$

Then apply $\frac{d}{d\ln x}=\frac{dx}{d\ln x}\frac{d}{dx}=x\frac{d}{dx}$.

I guess there are some restrictions though, especially $x\neq 0$ since the Logarithm is not defined then ($\alpha\neq0$ is caught by $e^{\ln\alpha}=\alpha$).

Answer (score 14):

More generally, there are the special linear conformal transformations SL(2,R) associated with the differential operators

$S_{-1}f(z)=\exp\left(a\frac d{dz}\right)f(z)=f(z+a)$

$S_{0}f(z)=\exp\left(bz\frac d{dz}\right)f(z)=f(e^b z)$

$S_{1}f(z)=\exp\left(cz^{2}\frac d{dz}\right)f(z)=f\left(\frac z{1-cz}\right)$

The $z^{m+1}\frac d{dz}$ (m=-1,0,1) are a representation of a subgroup of the infinite [Witt Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt_algebra) associated with the [Virasoro algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virasoro_algebra), and their exponential maps can be used to construct Möbius, or linear fractional, transformations.

For more info (combinatorics, generalizations), see my notes "Mathemagical Forests" (pages 13-15) at my little "[arxiv](https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2008/06/12/mathemagical-forests/)".

Also refer to [this question](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?p=3564501#post3564501) at Physics Forum.

(Update) Another way to look at the the scaling operator is

$S_{0}f(z)= exp[(e^t-1):zd/dz:]f(z)=exp[t\phi_{.}(:zd/dz:)]f(z)=exp(tzd/dz)f(z)$

where $(:zd/dz:)^n=z^n(d/dz)^n$  and $(\phi_{.}(x))^n=\phi_{n}(x)$ is the n’th [Bell/Touchard/exponential polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html) with the exponential generating function $exp[(e^t-1)x]=exp[t\phi_{.}(x)]$.

Edit 2/2014: Also more simply, $exp[(a-1):zd/dz:]f(z)=f(a·z)$. And, the next logical extension is to treat $a$ as an umbral variable, i.e., $a^n=a_n$, as Blissard did.

Edit 6/2014: An equivalent op, when acting on fcts. analytic at the origin, is $exp(a:xD_{x=0}:)$.

Applying the last two ops. with $a$ an umbral variable to $exp(x)$ gives the Euler or binomial transformation for exp. generating fcts., which can then be related to the Euler transform for ordinary generating functions through the Borel-Laplace transform. Then evaluating at $x=1$ gives the Euler summation for a series. To me, the differential ops. make these relations transparent.

Edit July 20, 2021:

In 1852 Charles Graves (brother of John Graves, the inventor of octonions in 1843) published "On a generalization of the symbolic statement of Taylor's theorem" in the Proc. of the Royal Irish Academy, presenting $e^{g(x)D} \; x = f^{(-1)}(1+f(x))$ where $g(x) = 1/f'(x)$, giving the examples for $g(x) = x^n$ for $n \geq 0$.

Comment: thanks, interesting point. The last identity can be seen from $z^2\frac d{dz}=-\frac d{d\frac1z}$, so there's an even more general expression for $m\ge1$ using $\frac d{dz^{-m}} = -\frac1m z^{-(m+1)}\frac d{dz}$

Comment: actually, this way around, all $m\in\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$ are acceptable

Comment: @Tobias,thanks for adding the Wiki links to my note on the Witt and Virasoro algebras. See my MF notes for general m, and the Addendum as well as http://oeis.org/A094638. Wolfdieter Lang has also explored the Witt　algebra (http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL12/Lang/lang.pdf).

Comment: normal ordering? this is getting related to QFT more than I expected...

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117287/motivation-of-virasoro-algebra/150935#150935 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145555/why-is-there-a-connection-between-enumerative-geometry-and-nonlinear-waves/181534#181534

Comment: Great, thanks for the links!

Comment: See also refs for https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172899/differential-operator-simplification/172900#172900