# What's umbral calculus about?

Tags: calculus, umbral-calculus

I've read Wikipedia about it and it says:

> In mathematics before the 1970s, the term umbral calculus referred to
>   the surprising similarity between seemingly unrelated polynomial
>   equations and certain shadowy techniques used to 'prove' them.

- What are these techniques?

> These similarities allow one to construct umbral proofs, which, on the
>   surface cannot be correct, but seem to work anyway.

- What does "seem to work" mean here?
- It seems that umbral calculus is a mathematical idea with almost no uses, why? (At least it's not so famous as calculus and algebra, for example.)

Comment: Calculus and algebra are massive branches of mathematics encompassing thousands of techniques each. It is far to much to demand of umbral calculus, which is essentially a single technique, to be equally useful.

Comment: "What are these techniques?" Aren't several examples given in the very Wikipedia article you're quoting?

Comment: Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra has a nice chapter on this, that might be a good place to read.

Comment: The Wikipedia article itself already gives good examples and also has references.

Comment: You can download some of Roman's articles on umbral calculus here: http://www.romanpress.com/MathArticles/MathArticles.htm

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Umbral relations shadow those of the basic binomial transform, revealing underlying connections between diverse areas of math (as Leibnitz himself predicted--see H. Davis "Theory of Linear Operators"):

[Edit June 17, 2021: A slightly different introductory presentatation is at MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42929/suggestions-for-good-notation/395605#395605).]

**I)** Umbral notation is brief and suggestive (courtesy of Blissard and contemporaries):

$ \displaystyle (a.)^n= a_n \;  \;  \; $ (umbral variable and lowering of superscript).

Expressing binomial convolution simply:

$$  \displaystyle (a. + b.)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}  \binom{n}{k} a_{k} b_{n-k} \; \;$$
(be careful to evaluate $(a.+b.)^0=a_0b_0$ and $(a.+b.)^1=a_0b_1+a_1b_0$),
$$ \displaystyle e^{a. \; x}= \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n \frac{x^n}{n!} \; \; ,$$

$$ \displaystyle e^{a.\;x}\; e^{b.\; x} = e^{(a. + b.)x}\; \; .$$

A more precise notation is to use $\langle a.^n \rangle = a_n$ to clearly specify when the lowering op, or evaluation of an umbral quantity, is to be done. E.g.,

$$\langle a.^n a.^m\rangle=\langle a.^{n+m}\rangle= a_{n+m} \ne a_n a_m= \langle a.^n\rangle\langle a.^m\rangle$$

and $$\langle\exp[\ln(1+a.x)]\rangle=\langle(1+a.x)\rangle=1+a_1x$$

$$\ne \exp[\langle\ln(1+a.x)\rangle]=\exp \left[ \sum_{n \ge 1} \langle\frac{a.^nx^n}{n}\rangle\right]=\exp\left[\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{a_nx^n}{n}\right]\; .$$

**II)** Same for umbralized ops, allowing succint specification and derivation of many relations, especially among special functions. A good deal of umbral calculus is about defining these ops for special sequences, such as the falling $(x)_{n}=x!/(x-n)!$ and rising factorials $(x)_{\bar{n}}=(x+n-1)!/(x-1)!$ and Bell polynomials $\phi_n(x)$.

Examples:

$ (:AB:)^n = A^n B ^n$  (defn. for order preserving exponentiation for any operators )

$$ (xD)^n = (\phi.(:xD:))^n = \phi_n(:xD:) \; \; ,$$

$$ e^{txD} = e^{t \phi.(:xD:)} \; \; .$$

From $xD \; x^{n} = n \; x^{n}$, it's easy to derive

$$e^{t\phi.(x)} = e^{x (e^t-1)} \; \; .$$

(See this [MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172955/ordinary-generating-function-for-bell-numbers/172969#172969) for the o.g.f.)

**III)** Umbral compositional inverse pairs allow for easy derivations of combinatorial identities and reveal associations among different reps of operator calculi.

Look at how this connects the distributive operator exponentiation $:xD:^n=x^nD^n$ to umbral lowering of superscripts. The falling factorials and Bell polynomials are an umbral inverse pair, i.e., $\phi_n((x).)=x^n=(\phi.(x))_n$. This is reflected in the functions $\log(1+t)$ and $e^t-1$, defining their e.g.f.s $e^{x\log(1+t)}$ and $e^{x(e^t-1)}$, being regular compositional inverses and to the lower triangular matrices containing the coefficients for the polynomials (the Stirling numbers of the first and second kinds) being multiplicative inverses, so we can move among many reps to find and relate many formulas. For the derivative op rep,

$$((xD).)^n=(xD)_n=x^nD^n=:xD:^n=(\phi.(:xD:)).^n=(\phi.(:xD:))_n,$$

so we have a connection to the umbral lowering of indices

$$:xD:^n=((xD).)^n=(xD)_n=x^nD^n.$$

**IV)** The generalized Taylor series or shift operator is at the heart of umbral calculus:

$$ e^{p.(x)D_y}f(y) = f(p.(x)+y)  \; , $$

(e.g., this entry on [A class of differential operators](http://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2015/08/23/a-class-of-differential-operators-and-the-stirling-numbers/#more-2614) and another on the [Bernoulli polynomials](https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/umbral-composition-of-the-bernoulli-polynomials-and-the-riemann-zeta-function/#more-1643)) with special cases

$$ e^{:p.(x) D_x:} f(x) = f(p.(x) + x) \; , $$ and

$$ e^{-(1-q.(x))D_y}y^{s-1} \; |_{y=1} = (1-(1-q.(x)))^{s-1} \; ,$$ giving a Gauss-Newton interpolation of $q_n(x)$ (shadows of the binomial relations).

It can often be used to easily reveal interesting combinatorial relations among operators. A simple example:

$$ e^{txD} f(x) = e^{t\phi.(:xD:)} f(x) = e^{(e^t-1):xD:} f(x) = f(e^{t}x) \; .$$
You could even umbralize $t$ to obtain the Faa di Bruno formula.
Try discovering some op relations with the Laguerre polynomials (hint--look at $:Dx:^n= D^nx^n$. Cf. [Diff ops and confluent hypergeometric fcts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107159/pochhammer-symbol-of-a-differential-and-hypergeometric-polynomials/107191#107191).).

As another example (added May 2015) of the interplay between differential operators, umbral calculus, and finite differences, note the relations for the Bell polynomials

$$\phi_{n}(:xD_x:)= \sum_{k=0}^n S(n,k)x^kD_x^k = (xD_x)^n=\sum_{j=0}^\infty j^n \frac{x^jD^j_{x=0}}{j!}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \left[\sum_{k=0}^j(-1)^k \binom{j}{k}k^n\right] \frac{x^jD_x^j}{j!} \;$$

and apply these operators on $x^m$, $e^x$, and $x^s$. (The $S(n,k)$ are the Stirling numbers of the second kind.)

I've used the power monomials $x^n$ and their associated raising and lowering ops, $x$ and $D_x$, but these relations are shadowed by the raising and lowering ops of all umbral sequences $p_n(x)$ such that $R \; p_n(x) = p_{n+1}(x)$ and $L \; p_n(x)  = n \;  p_{n-1}(x)$. (Shadows of Lie and quantum mechanics here also.)

**V)** (Added Sept. 2020): The generalized Chu-Vandermonde identitiy for the discrete convolution of binomial coefficients--integral to understanding properties of confluent hypergeomeric functions and their diff op reps--is easily derived from the umbral Sheffer calculus.

Binomial Sheffer sequence of polynomials (BSP) have e.g.f.s of the form

$$e^{x \; h(t)} = e^{t \; B.(x)},$$

where $h(t)$ and is invertible and vanishes at the origin. This implies

$$e^{(x+y)h(t)} = e^{t \; B.(x+y)} = e^{xh(t)}e^{yh(t)} = e^{t \; B.(x)}e^{t B.(y)} = e^{t(B.(x)+B.(y))},$$
so follows the accumulation property
$$(B.(x)+B.(y))^n = B_n(x+y).$$
The Stirling polynomials of the first kind, $ST1_n(x) = (x)_n$, are a BSP with $h(t)=\ln(1+t)$ and

$$\binom{x}{k} = \frac{ST1_k(x)}{k!},$$
so
$$(ST1.(x)+ST1.(y))^n = ST1_n(x+y)$$

implies directly the Chu-Vandermonde identity

$$\binom{x+y}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{x}{k} \binom{y}{n-k}.$$

Edit July 12, 2023:

I'd like to dispel the common jingoistic mantra--promoted by Roman and Rota and oft repeated (see [this MSE-Q](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101860/question-about-baffling-umbral-calculus-result/4728887#4728887))--that the reference to shadow in Sylvester's coining of 'umbral calculus' (umbra-umbrella-shadow) suggests the shadowy = dodgy = edgy nature of the techniques.

As I note above, umbral relations reflect / shadow  those of the binomial transform and, perhaps more accurately, the pair of umbral inverse sets of Pascal polynomials $Psc_{n;\pm}(x) = (x \pm 1)^n$. The ladder ops--the lowering / destruction / annihilation op $L$ and the raising / creation op $R$-- of these polynomials are $L_{\pm} = D$ and $R_{\pm}= (x\pm 1)$, which are conjugations of the simplest $L=D$ and $R=x$ for the power polynomials $Pwr_n(x) = x^n$ by the simple umbral substitution ops

$$Sub_{x^n \to Psc_{n;\pm}(x)} \; x^n = e^{\pm D} \; x^n = e^{(x\pm 1)D_{t=0}}\; t^n  = (x \pm 1)^n.$$

The raising ops for $Psc_{n,\pm}(x)$ are the [conjugations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class) / '[similarity transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity)'

$$R_{\pm} = e^{\pm D} \; x \; e^{\mp D}$$

and the lowering ops are the conjugations

$$L_{\pm} = e^{\pm D} \; D \; e^{\mp D}.$$

The ladder ops of all Sheffer polynomial sequences can be characterized by conjugations of the fundamental Graves-Pincherle-Lie-Weyl ladder ops $x$ and $D$ with the appropriate substitution ops. This conjugation relation ultimately allows us to claim that the nature of the umbral techniques shadow those of the binomial transform / convolution. See my pdf in my post "[The umbral compositional inverse of a Sheffer polynomial sequence and its lowering and raising operators](https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2023/07/04/the-umbral-compositional-inverse-of-a-sheffer-polynomial-sequence-and-its-lowering-and-raising-operators/)" for details.

Comment: I'm having introductory lectures in combinatorics. I'm amazed that Umbral Calculus is a lot similar to some of the things I've seen there, I thought it was nearer to real analysis. Although, as you pointed in the start of the text: It might have a lot of connections.

Comment: Could you recommend some really elementary introduction to umbral calculus? It seems really interesting, but I still don't have much background.

Comment: Master basic combinatorics first (binomials, Stirling numbers, Chu-Vandermonde identities--keeping an eye on their apps in analysis--check OEIS entries also) and linear algebra (linear functionals, dual spaces). Then you should be ready for Rota, Roman, et al., as Michael suggests.

Comment: Can't wait? Start studying the Appell polynomials, in particular, the Hermite and Bernoulli polynomials, and the three binomial Sheffer sequences the rising and falling factorials and Bell / Touchard polynomials. In parallel, look at finite differences and their differential operator reps. (Wiki refs again). I think after that you can easily make your own choices about what relevant operator calculi and integral transforms to explore. Use the umbral notation to simplify expressions and suggest formulas.

Comment: Thanks. I have one stupid question, why is checking the OEIS important? Is it because if one process in - say - combinatorics generates one sequence and another process in - say - analysis generates the same sequence, there is a connection between them? Can you provide-me a not too hard example in which that connection is important? (presuming my suggestion is the real reason why the OEIS checking is important).

Comment: Yep, the intersections inform. Also, you can often contribute something new yourself. Look at noncrossing partitions A134264.

Comment: This seems interesting, can you do something simple with this like demonstrate solving a quadratic equation please?

Comment: @Neil, not sure what you mean. Maybe try working out some of the equations with a low-order polynomial.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, it isn't really clear to me what's going on without a number example.  Can you use the method for example to show me how you would solve x^2+2x+1.  In the regular method you factor it into (x-1)^2 and then you know x = 1,1.  How do you do the same polynomial in umbral calculus?

Comment: Oh I didn't know.  I figured since you can use regular calculus to find the zeros of a quadratic that you could do it with umbral calculus also.

Comment: I changed a bunch of instances of things like $< a.^n a.^m>=< a.^{n+m}>$ to things like $\langle a.^n a.^m\rangle=\langle a.^{n+m}\rangle$.  I also deleted some superfluous instances of \displaystyle.  Why do you use \displaystyle in cases where you have an actual _display_ rather than _inline_ notation? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, residue from wordpress copy.

Comment: For some history and other details on the relation of operator calculus to Appell and more general Scheffer sequences, see The Theory of Linear Operators by H. T. Davis at http://archive.org/details/theoryoflinearop033341mbp

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116633/is-there-a-formula-similar-to-fxa-ea-fracddxfx-to-express-f-al/126744#126744

Comment: For an intro without reference to operational calculus see "Applications of the classical umbral calculus" by Gessel http://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Applications-of-the-Classical-Umbral-Calculus-Gessel/33a96e3ccc73c113526f4cf800ccb8a9c7b21ecb

Comment: Do you know how that operator that transforms powers of x into Bernoulli polynomials of x is called?

Comment: @Anixx, the Todd operator.

Comment: A look at some basic relations among differential operators, umbral substitution, and series summation: "A generalized Taylor series operator: Umbral shift, binomial transform, and interpolation" https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2019/08/22/a-generalized-taylor-series-operator-umbral-shift-binomial-transform-and-interpolation/

Comment: For some history and another approach to understanding umbral calculus, "An umbral setting for cumulants and factorial moments" by E. Di Nardo and D. Senato (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412052)

Comment: Rota: Although the notation of Hopf algebra satisfied the most ardent advocate of spic-and-span rigor, the translation of “classical” umbral calculus into the newly found rigorous language made the method altogether unwieldy and unmanageable. Not only was the eerie feeling of witchcraft lost in the translation, but, after such a translation, the use of calculus to simplify computation and sharpen our intuition was lost by the wayside…

Comment: @Neil, I have to backpedal a little on one of my earlier comments. Umbral calculus is related to proving or disproving that power series are hyperbolic, i.e., have only real zeros. In fact, this was probably a primary motivation for the development of Appell sequences with polynomials of the form $A_n(x)= (a.+x)^n$. See "Zeros of Entire Fourier Transforms" by Dimitrov and Rusev https://www.dcce.ibilce.unesp.br/~dimitrov/ProfRusev/EJA_Paper_24_02_11/Dim_Rus_main.pdf.

Comment: For some relations among matrix algebra and umbral calculus, see https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2020/09/23/appell-matrices/

Comment: See a simple but important example of the use of umbral calculus in my answer to the MSE-Q https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4624584/what-are-the-properties-of-umbra-with-moments-1-1-2-1-3-1-4-1-5

Answer (score 17):

From the Wikipedia article: "The combinatorialist John Riordan in his book *Combinatorial Identities* published in the 1960s, used techniques of this sort extensively."  There you see the classical umbral calculus.  Basically he pretends subscripts are exponents, and somehow it works.  Take a look at that book.  It doesn't require a lot of apparatus.

The 1978 paper by Roman and Rota, cited in the article, is the beginning of a technique for making the classical umbral calculus rigorous.

The 1975 paper by Rota, Kahaner, and Odlyzko appears to be a paper about Sheffer sequences, which are certain sequences of polynomials (see the Wikipedia article titled "Sheffer sequence").  If you lay that paper and the 1978 paper side-by-side, you can see that they're really two different ways of looking at the same thing.

In the mean time, look at the concrete examples in the Wikipedia article that you cited.

Is it useful?  I think one could argue about that.  But I don't want to try to make the case for its utility in research.

Comment: What you mean with useful? I've read a few stuff on the differences of pure and applied mathematics, considering the view of pure mathematics, this definition seems to don't exist.

Comment: For a simple use of umbral substitution in a current research paper, see p. 2 of "KP hierarchy of Hodge Integrals" http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.3263.

Comment: That is, pages 2, 4 and 7.

Comment: A nice example of the use of UC in contemporary research: "On the combinatorics of Riordan arrays and Sheffer polynomials: monoids, operads and monops"
Miguel A. Méndez and Rafael Sánchez https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.00336

Answer (score 3):

Blissard came up with this curious idea, if we take the expansion of the binomial to nth power and replace all the powers of $a$ with indexed terms of a sequnece, we can prove some identites easily:

$$ (1+a)^n \to \sum_i^n \binom{n}{i} a_i$$

In Modern language, this can be explained very simply. We are applying a **linear functional** on the algebra of polynomials which maps $a^i \to a_i$. The critical thing to understand is that during the initial conception of Umbrel Calculus, the ideas of linear functional and such were not common, hence people understood the power of this trick as magic.

Reference: Applications of the Classical Umbral Calculus, Ira M. Gessel

Comment: So Boole, Sylvester, and Cayley were ignorant of the nature of linear transformations? Sylvester and Cayley were adept at using the umbral calculus in invariant theory at a very complex level, and both introduced the concept of determinants and then matrices.

Comment: It's not to say they weren't intimately familiar with the nature of linear transformations (but I can't speak for what the OP really meant). The attribution is consistent with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus

Comment: @Chickenmancer, Wikipedia often repeats the common mantras and that entry is dismal. See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101860/question-about-baffling-umbral-calculus-result/4728887#4728887. As for the linear functional approach, see https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-13/issue-1/Review-Steven-Roman-The-umbral-calculus/bams/1183552628.pdf and the nonintuitive ad hoc first eqn on p. 75.