# Proving the Bernoulli number relation $(1+B)^n=B^n$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

We know that we can generate the Bernoulli numbers using the relation $(1+B)^n=B^{[n]}$ where $B_n$ is $n$th [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). But how we can prove this works? Thanks to all.

Edit 2: is there a website or book that can give me good information?

Comment: If $B_n$ is a Bernoulli number then what is $B$? What is $B^{[n]}$?

Comment: @SohamChowdhury for example :$(1+B)^2=B^{[2]}$
so $1+2B^{[1]}+B^{[2]}=B^{[2]}$ so $1+2B_1+B_2=B_2$ so $B_1=-1/2$

Comment: that way is only for Bernoulli number

Comment: is there any website or book can give me good information ?

Comment: As a possible "good information": you might look at/like http://go.helms-net.de/math/pascal/bernoulli_en.pdf , very elementary treatize which was just *motivated by that expression* with the Bernoulli-numbers. It was my first deeper encounter with number theory so please don't mind that it is much amateurish.

Comment: Hmm, while $(1+B)^2 = B^{[2]} \to B_1=-1/2$ - what does that make for $(1+B)^1  = B^{[1]} \to  B_1$ ? We've a contradiction ...

Comment: The relation simply doesn't hold for $n=1$, and it isn't expected to.

Comment: @anon: in the OP's question there is no such reservation. The same generosity: saying simply *"for n is [some formula]" valid* and not mentioning, that for $n=1$ this is not true, and that it is even not expected, came across me when I read in Eric Weissstein's mathworld-page for Bernoulli-numbers. I think such missing information at a formula intended for generality is not tolerable.

Comment: **1** [Umbral calculus - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus) **2** [Umbral calculus - Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Umbral_calculus) **3** [What's umbral calculus about? - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191752)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity can be proven using generating functions. We have

$$1=\frac{t}{e^t-1}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k\frac{t^k}{k!}\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{t^m}{(m+1)!}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{B_k}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k+1)!}\right)t^n. $$

Comparing coefficients of both sides yields for $n\ge1$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!(n-k+1)!}B_k=0\iff \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+1}{k}B_k=0\iff \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}B_k=B_{n+1}.$$

Formally this is the relation $(B+1)^{n+1}=B^{n+1}$ expanded via binomial theorem then with the powers taken from superscript to subscript. The identity sometimes takes the recursive form

$$B_n=-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+1}{k}B_k.$$

This proof is present in [these notes](http://math.ucsb.edu/~jcs/Bernoulli.pdf) on Bernoulli numbers in the section on basic properties.

There are many resources available on GF techniques, notably generatingfunctionology.