# Taylor Series: How can I expand this function $\sin (x) e^x$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have some doubts about the Taylor series expansion of $\sin x e^x$.

My first attempt resulted in:

$$x+(2x^2/2)+(2x^3/6)-(4x^5/120)$$

If someone could tell me if the Taylor expansion is correct, I would be really grateful.

Comment: $\sin(xe^x)$ or $\sin(x)e^x$?

Comment: $\sin (x) e^x$ is not an **equa**tion, where is the equal sign? EDIT: if $F(x)=\sin(x)e^x$ would be an equation then $F(x)$ or $x$ must be an unknown...

Comment: $sin(x) e^x$ is the correct form of the equation sorry for the mistakes...

Comment: it'll probably include a binomial, right?

Comment: You can use any number of free symbolic math apps on the Web to do a Taylor series expansion for you to check your computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: I assume that you are asking for the Taylor series of $f(x):=\sin(x)e^x$ around zero. Because $\sin$ and $\exp$ are both analytic functions who Taylor series around zero have infinite radius of convergence then

$$\mathcal T(\sin,0)(x)=\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\quad\text{and}\quad\mathcal T(e^x,0)=e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!},\quad x\in\Bbb C$$

$$\mathcal T(f,0)(x)=f(x)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k,\quad x\in\Bbb C$$

where $a_k:=\sum_{j=0}^kb_jc_{k-j}$ with $$b_j=[x^j]\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\quad\text{ and }\quad c_{k-j}:=[x^{k-j}]\sum_{h=0}^\infty\frac{x^h}{h!}$$

and $\mathcal T(f,a)$ means the Taylor series of $f$ around $a$. That is: if the functions are analytic the Cauchy product of Taylor series (around the same point) with radius of convergence $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ is the Taylor series of the product, with radius of convergence $\rho_3\ge\min\{\rho_1,\rho_2\}$.

Because $b_j=0$ when $j$ is even then

$$a_0=0,\quad a_1=b_1c_0=1,\quad a_2=b_1c_1=1,\quad a_3=b_1c_2+b_3c_0=1/2-1/6=2/6$$

and so on. With a bit of algebra we can see that

$$a_k=\frac1{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor}(-1)^j\binom{k}{2j+1}$$

Comment: So, that means that i can expand both parts individually and multiplying them, will i get the correct result if i do that?

Comment: if the functions that are multiplied are analytic, yes. You only need take care with the radius of convergence as I explained above. In this case is trivial because both radius of convergence are infinite, so the radius of convergence of the product is also infinite.

Answer (score 5):

$f(x)=e^x\sin x$ is the imaginary part of $e^xe^{ix}=e^{(1+i)x}$.
Now
$$e^{(1+i)x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1+i)^nx^n}{n!}$$
and so
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
where $a_n$ is the imaginary part of $(1+i)^n$.
Now $(1+i)^2=2i$ and $(1+i)^4=-4$. Therefore $a_{n+4}=-4a_n$.
So $a_{4m}=(-5)^ma_0=0$, $a_{4m+1}=(-4)^ma_1=(-4)^m$,
$a_{4m+2}=(-4)^ma_2=2(-4)^m$ and $a_{4m+3}=(-4)^ma_3=2(-4)^m$.
Alternatively,
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{n/2}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: aha... beautiful way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$f (x)= \sin (x) e^x$

$f' (x)= \cos (x) e^x + \sin (x) e^x$

$f'' (x)= 2 \cos (x) e^x $

$f''' (x)= - 2 \sin (x) e^x + 2 \cos (x) e^x$

$f'''' (x)= - 4 \sin (x) e^x $

$f''''' (x)= - 4 \cos (x) e^x - 4 \sin (x) e^x $

and

$f = f(0) + f'(0) x + f''(0) x^2/2 + f'''(0) x^3/6 +  f''''(0) x^4/24 + f'''''(0) x^5/120 + ...= 0 + x + x^2 + x^3/3 + 0 - x^5/30 + ...$

It seems correct!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
(\sin x) e^x &=& {1 \over 2i} (e^{(1+i)x} - e^{(1-i)x}) \\
&=& \sum_k { ((1+i)^k - \overline{(1+i)^k} ) \over 2 i} {x^k \over k!} \\
&=& \sum_k \operatorname{im} (1+i)^k {x^k \over k!} \\
&=& \sum_k {\sqrt{2^k} \over k!} \sin ({k\pi \over 4}) x^k
\end{eqnarray}
The later follows from $1+i = \sqrt{2} e^{i {\pi \over 4}}$.

This holds for complex $x$ as well, of course.

The first four terms are $a_0 = 0, a_1=1, a_2 =1 , a_3 = {1 \over 3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$\begin{array}\\
(fg)^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (f)^{(k)}(g)^{(n-k)},\\
(fg)(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(fg)^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{n!}(fg)^{(n)}(0)x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{n!}x^n\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (f)^{(k)}(0)(g)^{(n-k)}(0)\\
\end{array}
$

If
$g(x) = e^x$,
$g^{(n)}(x) = e^x$
so
$g^{(n)}(0) = 1$.

Therefore
$(fe^x)(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{n!}x^n\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (f)^{(k)}(0)
$.

If
$f(x)
=\sin(x)$,
for
$n = 0, 1, 2, 3$
we have,
repeating with period $4$,
$f^{(n)}(x)
=\sin(x),
\cos(x),
-\sin(x),
-\cos(x)
$
so
$f^{(n)}(0)
=0, 1, 0, -1
$.

Therefore
$(\sin(x)e^x)(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{n!}x^n\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} [0, 1, 0, -1]
$
so that,
using the dot product notation,
$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} [0, 1, 0, -1]
=\\
(0)\cdot (1) =0, \\
(0, 1)\cdot (1, 1)= 1,\\
(0, 1, 0)\cdot (1, 2, 1)= 2,\\
(0, 1, 0, -1)\cdot (1, 3, 3, 1) = 2,\\
(0, 1, 0, -1, 0)\cdot (1, 4, 6, 4, 1) = 0,\\
(0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1)\cdot (1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1)= -4,\\
$

so the coefficients are
$0, 1, 2/2=1, 2/6 = 1/3, 0,
-4/120 = -1/30
$.

The first few terms 
of the power series are
therefore
$\sin(x)e^x
=x+x^2+\frac13 x^3-\frac1{30}x^5
$.

This is confirmed
by Wolfy.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, using [umbral notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191752/whats-umbral-calculus-about/1085165#1085165), the product of two exponential generating functions (e.g.fs) $f(x)=e^{a.x}$ and $g(x)=e^{b.x}$, or two formal Taylor series, is the e.g.f.

$$h(x) = f(x)g(x) = e^{a.x}e^{b.x}=e^{(a.+b.)x}=e^{c.x}$$

where

$$c_n=(c.)^n=(a.+b.)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \; \binom{n}{k} a_k b_{n-k} \; .$$

In your particular case, we can choose $a_n=1$ for all $n $ and $b_n = sin (\pi n/2). $

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\left.\totald[n]{\bracks{\expo{x}\sin\pars{x}}}{x}\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 0} & =
\left.\totald[n]{}{x}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
\totald[n - k]{\expo{x}}{x}\,\totald[k]{\sin\pars{x}}{x}\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 0} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose 2k + 1}\pars{-1}^{k}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \ic}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose 2k + 1}\ic^{2k + 1} =
{1 \over \ic}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\ic^{k}\,{1 - \pars{-1}^{k} \over 2}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2\ic}\bracks{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\ic^{k} - \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-\ic}^{k}} =
\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\ic^{k} = \Im\pars{1 + \ic}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
\Im\pars{2^{n/2}\expo{\ic n\pi/4}} = 2^{n/2}\sin\pars{n\pi \over 4}
\end{align}

> Then,

$$
\bbx{\expo{x}\sin\pars{x} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{2^{n/2}\sin\pars{n\pi/4} \over n!}\,x^{n}}
$$