# Exponential of a power of the differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, taylor-expansion, lie-algebras, exponentiation

In relation to this question: [Exponential of a polynomial of the differential operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902514/exponential-of-a-polynomial-of-the-differential-operator)

Is there an expression for $\exp(aD^n)f(x)$ similar to $\exp(aD)f(x)=f(x+a)$?

Comment: Has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2108889/362193).