# Can there be a finite closed form for the one dimensional heat kernel $e^{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}}$ in operator calculus?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, functional-equations, quantum-field-theory

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807216/how-to-give-a-closed-form-to-eax-fracddx-bxif-in-physicists-st) we manage to show the existence of a closed form for arbitrary $e^{a(x) \frac{d}{dx} + b(x)I}$ as a single term of the form $k_1(x) f(k_2(x))$ where $k_1, k_2$ obey an interesting formula.

I now want to turn my attention to $e^{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}}$ which (thanks to Sri Tata for pointing it out) can be thought of as a [one dimensional heat kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel). Is there any formula involving finitely many pairs of functions $q_1(x), p_1(x) , ... q_n(x), p_n(x)$ and finitely many non-negative integers $c_1 ... c_n$ such that

$$ e^{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}} =  q_1(x)f^{(c_1)}(p_1(x)) + ... +   q_n(x)f^{(c_n)}(p_n(x))$$

Where the $(c_i)$ refer to derivatives.

I would suspect the answer is "no" since heat kernels have been known for a long time so we would have found a closed form by now. But I'm not even sure what kinds of tools are required to prove a result like this.

Would something like [Differential Algebra or Picard Vessiot Theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432263/is-there-a-theory-of-elementary-closed-form-solution-at-the-operator-level-for)  work in this setting?

Comment: This is related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483637/what-is-the-property-of-the-exponential-of-second-derivative-expd2-dx2 and interestingly suggests that if we open ourselves to including integrals, then this problem definitely has a finite solution.

Comment: [Near duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872197/evaluation-of-exp-lefta-fracd2dx2-rightfx).

Comment: I deleted my comment since it seemed standoffish when that wasn’t my intent.

Comment: Re: Infinite Lie Algebras, yes in general we should not expect these formulas to work out nicely. I guess knowing a concrete toolkit to check such would be cool