# Exponential of the differential operator $x \frac{d}{dx}$

Tags: operator-theory, differential-operators, matrix-exponential

I am studying conformal field theory, and I have run into an problem with calculations involving the quantum-mechanical translation and dilatation operators. It actually boils down to an issue about ordinary differential operators.

Consider an analytic function $\phi\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Define two differential operators
$\mathcal{P} = \frac{d}{dx}$ and $\mathcal{D} = x \frac{d}{dx}$. The goal is to compute $e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} \phi(a)$ for $a, \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$. I have two different methods which give different results.

**Method 1**: Like in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116633/is-there-a-formula-similar-to-fxa-ea-fracddxfx-to-express-f-al), we write $\mathcal{D} = \frac{d}{d\ln x}$ and find
$$ e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} \phi(a) = e^{\varepsilon \frac{d}{d\ln x}} \phi(e^{\ln a}) = \underline{\phi(e^{\varepsilon} a)} $$
which follows from the Taylor expansion of $\phi(e^y)$ around $y = \ln a$.

**Method 2**: We note that $e^{a\mathcal{P}} \phi(0) = e^{a\frac{d}{dx}} \phi(0) = \phi(a)$, which follows from the Taylor expansion of $\phi(x)$ around $x = 0$. We can therefore write
$$ e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} \phi(a) = e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} e^{a\mathcal{P}} \phi(0) = e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} e^{a\mathcal{P}} e^{-\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} \phi(0). $$
The final factor $e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} \phi(0)$ is equal to $\phi(0)$, by Method 1 or by noting that setting $x = 0$ kills all terms except the first in the expansion $e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} \phi(0) = \sum_{n = 0} \frac{\varepsilon^n}{n!} \left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n \phi(0)$.

We then write
$$ e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} e^{a\mathcal{P}} e^{-\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} = e^{a e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} \mathcal{P} e^{-\varepsilon\mathcal{D}}} $$
(which follows termwise from the expansion of $e^{a\mathcal{P}}$) and use the [nameless identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) (it seems to be called Hadamard's lemma or the Hausdorff formula?)
$$ e^A B e^{-A} = e^{[A,\cdot]} B = B + [A,B] + \frac{1}{2}[A,[A,B]] + \cdots $$
and calculate the commutator $[\mathcal{D}, \mathcal{P}] = -\mathcal{P}$ to evaluate
$$ e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} \mathcal{P} e^{-\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} = e^{\varepsilon[\mathcal{D}, \cdot]} \mathcal{P} = e^{-\varepsilon} \mathcal{P}. $$
Putting everything together, we have
$$ e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} \phi(a) = e^{a e^{-\varepsilon} \mathcal{P}} \phi(0) = \underline{\phi(e^{-\varepsilon} a)}. $$

**Question**: Why do these two methods give different results? There seems to be a sign error somewhere, but I have tried and failed to find it for several hours, so I am starting to suspect that there may be a deeper problem with my reasoning. Is there a flaw in my Method 2?

Comment: The problem is already in the assertion $e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} \phi(a) = e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} e^{a\mathcal{P}} \phi(0)$. Consider the simple case $\phi(x)=x$. We have $[e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} x]_{x=a} = [e^\varepsilon x]_{x=a} = e^\varepsilon a$, but $[e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} e^{a\mathcal{P}} x]_{x=0} = [e^{\varepsilon\mathcal{D}} (x+a)]_{x=0} = [e^\varepsilon x+a]_{x=0} = a$. In this context one should in general be careful with the usual notation for evaluating functions at a point because it can be ambiguous and lead to confusion.